# Floats issue in IE

Tags: css, css-float

I've just launched a site for a client at work and just realized there's a bug in IE when you click on a hyperlink the hyperlink disappears up to the top of the page.

Really not sure why. I'm sure it's a floats issue and me not understanding.

http://stylistic.get-there-sooner.com/

```
<div id="tweets">
<h2>Join the Conversation #StylisticQ550</h2>
<div class="tweet"></div>
<div id="tweets_right"><h3>Follow us on Twitter</h3>
 <p><a href="http://www.twitter.com/Stylistic_UK" target="_new" style="display: block;    width: 181px; height: 32px; border: 0px; background: url(http://www.replyonline.co.uk/eloqua/fujitsu/15882/images/twitter_button.gif) no-repeat; text-indent: -9999px;">Stylistic_UK</a></p>
</div>
</div>
```

If someone could look at my amateurish code and see what the issue is that would be awesome. Extra brownie points to someone who can explain floats to me properly too ;-)

Thanks

Comment: is it just the twitter button? It seems to be working fine for me, but I'm using IE9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could well be because you're making the < a > tag for the link a block element which isn't allowed by the standards, and possibly the gods of IE.

Could also be the fact that target="_new" isn't a valid standard target. Try _blank instead, or just "new" if you want one consistent other window to navigate to. This could be throwing earlier versions of IE. God knows why it'd throw it to the top though (in a rage perhaps).

Will need some more information to look further though, IE versions tested etc.

P.S that link completely kills my IE7 around 15 script errors.